# Can't receive push notificatons on a device despite the implementation is correct

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

In brief, the problem is that I'm testing the push notifications on two devices. `phoneA` is iPhone 5, `phoneB` is iPhone 4. When I send message from `phoneB` to `phoneA` it works correctly, but when I send it from `phoneA` to `phoneB` nothing happens.

The push messages are enabled on both devices, so I have no idea what causes this issue. Is it possible that `phoneA` cached something in a bad way?

I deleted and installed the app several times, and tried with new certificates, but actually both phone using the same implementation so it must work.

If you have any idea or experienced something like this in the past, I would be very happy if you could give me some ideas. Maybe it's a trivial problem, but actually I feel I've lost.

Answer (score 1):

Store your udid and device token in nsuserdefaults and send both every time to your server with the push notification message.

Comment: Why? I don't understand why should I send the device token to another device.

Comment: not to another device you have to send that to your server

Comment: on server side they store your udid and devise token for the uniqueness of your device